# How to stop browser on exception

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, exception, browser

### TLDR: Is there a way to stop execution on exception in the browser?

So i have this weird scenario.

Im writing a front-end application in `Angular2` and i have a Modal with a form in it for adding entries to the back-end's DB.

My Modal's Component has an `@Output` property as follows:

```
@Output() onSubmit: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();
```

The parent subscribes with a refetching method to this onSubmit event and on success:

```
if (isSuccessful) {
    this.onSubmit.emit();
    closeModal.exec();
}
```

It used to update the items display when I refetched (refreshing only the display component), and now it does not,
instead it refreshes the whole pages makes me start from the beginning.

I tried debugging it and I couldn't place a breakpoint.

What I could notice is that right before the page refreshes an exception pops in the console and disappears on refresh.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to stop on exception within the chrome dev tools by navigating to the sources tab and selecting "Pause on Exceptions", which has a shortcut of F8

[image: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/images/track-exceptions-pause-execution.jpg]

The chrome dev tools can be opened with:

- Windows: F12
- Mac: alt+cmd+j

Further information can be found here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/track-exceptions#pause-on-javascript-exceptions

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what i was looking for ! :)